# Spring Cloud Data Flow Task logs

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-dataflow

I am running a Spring Cloud Data Flow in local and I want to override the path of the task logs.

```
    java -jar spring-cloud-dataflow-server-2.0.0.M1.jar ^
  --spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dataflow ^
  --spring.datasource.username=root ^
  --spring.datasource.password=password ^
  --spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver ^
  --spring.cloud.deployer.local.working-directories-root=C:/logs
```

I've tried to include the property in dataflow-server.yml of spring-cloud-starter-dataflow-server-local projet as

```
spring:
  cloud:
    deployer:
      local:
        working-directories-root: c:/logs/spring-cloud-dataflow
```

When I launch the task, I obtain:

```
Logs will be in C:\Users\Usuario1\AppData\Local\Temp\task-app...
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're on Windows, you may have to try the path as: `c:\\logs\\spring-cloud-dataflow`.

Here's the [piece of logic](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-deployer-local/blob/master/spring-cloud-deployer-local/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/deployer/spi/local/LocalDeployerProperties.java#L138) that takes the supplied directory path to where the logs will be transferred.